# How to remove/delete a shape at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, shapes

I draw a hexagon at runtime in vbExpress2008:

```
Private Sub Panel2_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel2.Paint

    Dim Hpoint As Point
        
    yada yada yada

    e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(p, Points)

End Sub
```

Now how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

As your code is now, you can't remove it. Every time that code is executed, it will draw that shape, so there's nothing to remove. If you want to remove it then there has to be something to remove. That's why you should store the data that represents the drawing in one or more fields and then get the data from there each time you want to draw. If you have a field of type `List(Of Point())` then you can add and remove `Point` arrays as required and then force a `Paint` event. In the event handler, you get the current data and draw it, so anything you remove from that `List` will be removed from drawing. E.g.

```vb
Private polygons As New List(Of Point())

Private Sub AddPolygon(points As Point())
    polygons.Add(points)
    Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub RemovePolygon(points As Point())
    polygons.Remove(points)
    Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    For Each polygon In polygons
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, polygon)
    Next
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if it's just one polygon that you want to show or hide, you could still hard-code it in the `Paint` event handler but use an `If` statement that tests a field of type `Boolean`. You can then just toggle that field and invalidate to hide and show that one polygon.